# How to treat data for Bayesian VARs

Tags: time-series, bayesian, vector-autoregression, kalman-filter, time-varying-covariate

I am working on a project where I need to implement a time varying structural VAR. From my understanding this uses the Kalman filter and is basically a Bayesian tool.

From frequentist time series analysis I know that you would usually make your data stationary and test for cointegration. And then after building a model I would test for serial correlation and normality in the residuals. Is any or all of that necessary for Bayesian analysis?

I am relatively new to any time series analysis, let alone the Bayesian stuff. So if any other information is required to answer this question please let me know.